# logging hibernate queries with log4j when using servlet filter for open session in view pattern

Tags: hibernate, log4j, trace, open-session-in-view

First of all thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I'll start with my environment:
Primefaces 3.5
Hibernate 4.3.2
Glassfish 3.1.2

My problem is this: I want to log the sql queries hibernate does using log4j(and the parameters bound to those queries). The logging used to work until I decided to implement the [Open Session in View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern. Now the logs only contain the information from this filter (like "Starting a database transaction", etc.).

My log4j.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="production"
              class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">                        
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="app.log"/>  
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz" />

        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="debugfile"
              class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="debug.log"/>  
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="debug.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz" />

        </rollingPolicy>        

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>        
    </appender>

    <appender name="hibernatefile"
              class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="hibernate.log"/>  
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="hibernate.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz" />

        </rollingPolicy>


        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false">
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="hibernatefile"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" >
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="hibernatefile"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="hibernatefile" />
    </logger>

    <root>        
        <appender-ref ref="debugfile" />
        <appender-ref ref="production" />        
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The trace, info and other information from hibernate are not printed anywhere.

Thank you for your help,

Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I reached a conclusion on this issue. There is not a problem with the combination of these technologies and/or patterns but with the version of Hibernate. I used Hibernate 3 before and the logging went just fine but according to this documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging starting with Hibernate 4.0 they gave up on slf4j as the logging facade and they switched to JBoss logging. From this link (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Logging) it seems that JBoss logging has a variant that uses log4j but unfortunately I haven't managed to configure the whole environment to use JBoss logging instead of slf4j. For my application I reverted to Hibernate 3 and the logging is going just fine.

If there is someone that used Hibernate 4 with JBoss logging and log4j and has some sample configuration I think it would be appreciated by many people as I haven't found any relevant information in my searches.

Thank you for any relevant information you might have.